# I'm attempting to write a stored procedure that can read from a file and act on the contents

Tags: sql-server

I have a text file filled with `SELECT` statements that I would like to reference from a stored procedure. This is what my text file looks like:

```
SELECT '4200100116' AS [SRC_GEOID]
       ,SUM([Workers_in_Flow]) 
FROM [table] 
WHERE [DEST_GEOID] IN ('4200100116'
                      ,'4200105880'
                      ,'4200132144'
                      ,'4213357872')
```

I want to iterate through the text file and run these commands and append the results to a table. Is this possible? If so, how?

I've looked into T-SQL and gotten conflicting ideas on whether that's what I want or not. Also, I've learned about `BULK INSERT` but that seems to be more about inserting into a table whereas I want to run the actual commands and append the results.

Comment: Is powershell an option for you? if so, i can whip up an example

Answer (score 2):

This can be done simply with powershell. Use [get-content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) to get queries from file, [invoke-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) to run the queries, and [write-sqltabledata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/write-sqltabledata?view=sqlserver-ps) to output results to table. Save example below to .ps1 and run in powershell session passing the path to file with queries. (ex. C:\you\powershell> .\run-tsql.ps1 C:\temp\sql_queries.txt)

```
#paramter passed to script
param( [string] $auditlist)

#read contents of file
$queries = Get-Content $auditlist

#adds sql server module to get the sql server commands
import-module sqlserver

#cycle though all results retrived from file
foreach ($query in $queries)
{
    #run each command and load into table
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance <instance name> -database <databasename> -query $query -OutputAs DataTables |Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance <instance name> -DatabaseName <dbname> -SchemaName <schema> -TableName <table>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL definitely is not the best tool for this job, but if that's what you want to use then you could get the contents of the file into a table with `Bulk Insert`, and then iterate through the table to run the `Select` statements. You'll need a way to identify which row contains the statement you want to run, and once you have that you can assign the statement to a variable and execute it with `sp_executesql`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is to simple, but you can copy & paste the text file into a query window on SSMS and then execute it.